# Store in an ArrayList

Tags: java

How could i store the below code in an array list using Java? Im stuck. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
System.out.println("Please enter Officer's First Name");
firstName = input.next();
officerObject.setOfficerFirstName(firstName);
System.out.println("Enter Officer's Last Name");
lastName = input.next();
officerObject.setOfficerLastName(lastName);
System.out.println("Enter Officer's Badge Number");
badgeNum = input.next();
officerObject.setOfficerBadgeNum(badgeNum);
System.out.println("Enter Officer's Precint");
precint = input.next();
officerObject.setOfficerPrecint(precint);
```

Comment: What is `officerObject`? And how many do you want to store?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch **What is officerObject**, only James_Bond knows that :)

Comment: You don't store *code* in an `ArrayList`, you store *data*, and you usually store data by calling the `add()` method. Which part of creating an `ArrayList` and/or calling `add()` is troubling you?

Comment: @ShayHaned I double-o know that, that's why I asked!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I triple-o know that you already know that :D but I meant James_Bond from the movies :D

Comment: Hey guys, you made me smile :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ArrayList to store variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066954/using-arraylist-to-store-variables)

Answer (score 2):

Create an array list with `List<YOUR OBJECT TYPE> array = new ArrayList<>();` and then use `array.add(officerObject);` to add it to the array list.

Answer (score 0):

Well as he said use a List look

First it could be use like this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
    Officer officerObject = new Officer();

    System.out.println("Please enter Officer's First Name");
    officerObject.setOfficerFirstName(input.next());
    System.out.println("Enter Officer's Last Name");
    officerObject.setOfficerLastName(input.next());
    System.out.println("Enter Officer's Badge Number");
    officerObject.setOfficerBadgeNum(input.next());
    System.out.println("Enter Officer's Precint");
    officerObject.setOfficerPrecint(input.next());

    List<Officer> officer = new ArrayList<Officer>();
    officer.add(officerObject);

    for(Officer of: officer){
        System.out.println(of.getOfficerFirstName());
        System.out.println(of.getOfficerLastName());
        System.out.println(of.getOfficerBadgeNum());
        System.out.println(of.getOfficerPrecint());
    }
```